# Using BBones on Sketchfab

Tags: animation, armature

I am animating my model using bendy bones. When I upload the model to Sketchfab, the bbones work like normal armatures. They loose their bendiness.

I noticed that bendy bones appear to be made up internally of normal armatures, so I was wondering if there was some way to explode out these 'internal armatures' once I am done animating, just so I can upload my model to Sketchfab.

Or maybe there is some other way to bake the animation?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be helpful to export an animated OBJ sequence

Comment: Nice suggesting, I will try it out, though my model is fairly detailed and the sketchfab documentation notes that it could be really slow/laggy so it might not work for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

given that bendy-bones are specific to Blender, they aren't supported out of the box on Sketchfab. It may be worth posting this question to the forums at Sketchfab. Perhaps another Blender artist there has tried something similar?

https://forum.sketchfab.com/c/support/blender

Paul
Artist Evangelist, Sketchfab

Comment: Hey Paul thanks for the reply, yeah I am aware they aren't supported nor do I expect support for it, hence why I was seeking an way around the issue, heh. I've searched around a lot and OBJ sequences seem to be the only reliable way.